# VS2013 Developer Command Prompt PATH differs from cmd.exe PATH

Tags: command-line, mysql, windows-10, path, visual-studio-2013

On Windows 10, I installed MySQL server 5.6 with the VS 2013 integration option.  Now when I open the VS2013 Developer Command Prompt, I get:

> 'MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

I realized it was a %PATH% issue so I added the path to MySQL\bin in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment\Path and re-opened the command prompt.  Still got the error.  Rebooted the computer.  Still got the error.

I re-opened regedit and the path was as I amended it.  I went through Environment Variables in System/Advanced settings and the User PATH and System PATH both matched the change I made in the registry.

Weird thing is when I ECHO %PATH% it doesn't match.

Comment: Have you tried cd (the path of VS2013) then enter. Then the command you want to type

Comment: Are you starting the Developer Command Prompt as an Administrator?

Comment: Yes heavyd, starting the prompt as admin

Comment: Racing121, I am trying to get at the root of why the PATH in the Developer Command prompt does not match the System PATH environment variable or the User Path environment variable and how I can sync it up to stop getting this error on every launch.

Answer (score 0):

If you open a VS developer command prompt and the PATH environment variable contains something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5` (ends there), the problem is related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32781886/243572). The full path should end with `MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5`.

Follow the instructions there to fix both of the problematic entries (yes, there are two, they are in the `Path` system variable and the first is also blocking the rest from being included). Keep in mind that the quotes will **not** show up in the list the next time you open the environment variables dialog. You have to reboot for the changes to take effect.